# Anaconda prompt closes rapidly

Tags: windows-10, anaconda

So I had initially installed keras in conda environment and later decided to uninstall it.

After this, whenever I try to open my anaconda prompt it crashes within milliseconds.

I barely managed to stop it from exiting and these are the errors:

[image]

Comment: Did you try re-installing?

Comment: No! I wanted to go ahead other deep learning packages.